# glRotatef rotates the camera instead of the object

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, sdl-2

I need to create a virtual trackball with c++. I have made all the calculations and I can find the rotation angle and axis values. My object rotates as I intented with every mouse drag but the problem is after every rotation it goes back to its initial position.

So I figured out that I need to get the current modelview matrix, multiply it by the rotation matrix then load the result back to the opengl.

I have tried it but unfortunately, glRotatef rotates my camera instead of the object. Here is my function to draw the scene

```
//--- Drawing code ---------------------------------------

/** Drawing code for one frame. */
void drawGLScene ()
{
  // Real time in seconds.
  GLfloat t = frameStat->frameStart( width, height );

  // Clear the frame buffer and the depth buffer
  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

  // Set current model-view transform:
  glLoadIdentity();

  // Looking from "camera" to the "center" point (y-axis defines the "up" vector)
  gluLookAt( 0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f,
             center[ 0 ], center[ 1 ], center[ 2 ],
             0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );

  if (dragging)
      glLoadMatrixf(matModelView.array());

  glScalef( zoom, zoom, zoom );

#ifdef USE_VBO
  // scene rendering using VBO buffers:
  scene.render();

#else

  // client-side vertex arrays (cube):
  glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), vert );    // specify vertex data array
  glColorPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), vert + 3 ); // specify vertex color array

  glDrawElements( GL_QUADS, sizeof(ind) / sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ind );

#endif

  frameStat->swapBuffers( drawStat );            // SDL_GL_SwapWindow() and frame statistics
}

//--- Event handling -------------------------------------

/** Function to release/destroy our resources and restore the old desktop. */
void Quit ( int returnCode )
{
  scene.deleteBuffers();

  if ( glcontext )
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext( glcontext );

  // Clean up the window ..
  SDL_Quit();

  // .. and exit appropriately
  exit( returnCode );
}
```

And here is my mouse handling functions, I am excluding the release function since it is trivial.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------
//  Mouse handling:

void handleMouseMove ( SDL_Event &ev )
{

  if ( ev.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT && dragging )
  {
    rotation.set(MI_IDENTITY);
    rotation.rotate(5, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    matModelView = matModelView * rotation;
  }
}

void handleMousePress ( SDL_Event &ev )
{

  if ( ev.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT )
  {
    dragging   = true;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, (GLfloat *)matModelView.array());
    rotation.set(MI_IDENTITY);
  }
}
```

`matModelView` and `rotation` are 4x4 matrices. In this code, I am not included my trackball calculations. Here, I just expect it to rotate by 5 degree through the x axis as long as mouse dragging .

Maybe it is so simple but I am stuked into this point. Any guideness, code samples would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
matModelView = matModelView * rotation;
```

To this:

```
matModelView = rotation * matModelView;
```